# Securing controller action called from a webjob

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-webjobs

I have a MVC web site deployed in Azure, where I need to allow users to generate a pdf file from a html page. I do this by invoking wkhtmltopdf.exe within a WebJob called from a controller action. The html page rendered is produced by another controller action that returns an ActionResult.

Everything works fine when I decorate the action (that renders the html for the pdf) with [AllowAnonymous] but I would like to secure it somehow.

Is it possible to authenticate a request from a web job or have mysecureaction return its data only to those requests that originate from the web job?

Here's my web job code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  if (args.Length == 2)
  {
    var URL = args[0];
    var filename = args[1];

    try
    {
      using (var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
      {
        var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        {
          FileName = "wkhtmltopdf.exe",
          Arguments = URL + " " + filename,
          UseShellExecute = false,
        };
        p.StartInfo = startInfo;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();
      }

      // here save the pdf file to azure blob storage
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { /*error handling*/ }
    }
  }
```

And here's the code that calls the web job:

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority +         
Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
string Url = baseUrl + "/mycontroller/mysecureaction/" + id.ToString();
string filename = "filename.pdf";

try
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myazurewebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    var userName = "$myazurewebappuser";
    var password = "myazurewebapppassword";
    var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    var authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
       Convert.ToBase64String(
   encoding.GetBytes(string.Format($"{userName}:{password}"))));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;
    var content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent("");

    HttpResponseMessage response =
  await client.PostAsync($"api/triggeredwebjobs/myWebJob/run?arguments={Url} {filename}", content);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       //error handling
    }
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //error handling
}


byte[] file = null;
try
{
  using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
    // retrieve the file from blob storage
    file = client.DownloadData("https://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/pdf/" + filename);
  }
}
catch (Exception ex) { /*error handling*/ }

// return the file to the user
```

And obviously here's the action the web job calls to get the html

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult mysecureaction(int? id)
{
  SomeData model = new SomeData();
  // get some data from db using id
  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not seem like a good use of a WebJob. WebJobs are not normally invoked by the web application, nor do they themselves send requests to the web app. Instead, consider a couple alternatives:

You can do the work directly from within your app instead of using a WebJob, which isn't buying you much here.

You can have the communication between the app and the WebJob done via a queue instead of via direct http messages. e.g. the web app adds work item to the queue, and the WebJob picks them up, e.g. using  the WebJobs SDK.

Comment: Thank You, this is an excellent comment. The reason I chose to use a WebJob was the pdf conversion executable, which can't be used in Azure directly. I'll start looking into how to implement a queue, I'll appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction on specifics.

Comment: @crazysnake The Web App and the WebJobs run in identical sandboxes,, so if something is possible in a WebJob, it will also work in a Web App. See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks) for a list of supported and unsupported PDF tools.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks David! According to the materials I found before I was under the impression it was not possible to run external executables within the Azure sandbox, but creating my own wrapper class library did the trick perfectly. Also, I can use the AllowAnonymous attribute without any problems.

Comment: I'll mark David's comment as answer as it led me to a much better solution that also fixed securing the controller action. This is what I used as reference: https://beeming.net/just-coding/2017/5/converting-html-to-pdf-using-c-and-magic